# How to typeset math inline

Tags: math-mode

I would like to have the following inline:

```
We have these two points \textbf{a_1} and \textbf{a_2} etc
```

Once I select typeset I get a flag that I am missing $

So I tried this next:

```
We have these two points {${\textbf{a_1}}$} and {${\textbf{a_2}}$} etc
```

I got the same flag ... missing $

Interestingly if I use the following:

```
We have these two points \textbf{a} and \textbf{b} etc
```

things work out just fine.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\textbf` is invalid in math mode. If you want to have bold math, use either `\mathbf{...}` or `\boldmath` (the later requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this should work: `$\mathbf{a_1}$`, and so on.  (if you want only the letter to be bold: `$\mathbf{a}_1$`.  this is a comment rather than an answer because i'm not in a position to check.)

Comment: Thank-you to both the answers ... is there a way for me to show that the question has been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_` is only valid in math mode, it doesn't work outside of it.

`\textbf{...}` - as the name rather suggests - is a text mode command. Using `\textbf{...}` - whether within math mode or outside of it - puts you in text mode. The argument of `\textbf{...}` is typeset in text mode.

As such, you cannot use `_` within `\textbf{...}`.

Try

```
$\mathbf{a_{1}}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$\textbf{...}$` isn't allowed since `\textbf` is meant for text mode only.

There are multiple ways to achieve bold math, depending on the desired output.

`\mathbf` will print bold in math, but the letters are upright whereas `\boldmath` and `\bm` produces italic letters.

There is `\boldsymbol` (also `amsmath`) also for symbols that are not printed in bold by `\mathbf`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}    


We have these two points $\mathbf{a_1}$ and $\mathbf{a_2}$

We have these two points $\bm{a_1}$ and $\bm{a_2}$

\boldmath We have these two points $a_1$ and $a_2$\unboldmath

\end{document}
```

[image]